# How to create Fixed readonly prefix on input?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an input called user as below:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="User_Name">{{"UserName" | localize}} *</label>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="User"
[(ngModel)]="userform.User">
</div>
```

When the page is loaded, I want to create a function that places user type as a prefix in the input for user name, and that prefix should be readonly. But the user should be able to add the username after the prefix.

Example:(Admin and Student are user types that should be readonly and passed as parameter to the function). The user then adds the username in the same input box.

- Admin_John
- Admin_Tom
- Student_Jerry

I have tried to create a function as below and call it in the `ngOnInit()`function:

```
addPrefix(userName: string) {
this.userform.user = userName;
}
```

It does add the prefix, except that the prefix is not read only. Can anyone assist with this please?

Comment: Are you by any chance using Angular Material?

Comment: No, unfortunately I am not using angular materials.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options to achieve this functionality:

1) You can create a directive specific to this input element which adds the prefix and prevents it's deletion.

2) You can use one-way binding instead of two-way binding. [(ngModel)] -> [ngModel]
And also add a callback method like (ngModelChange)="setName($event)" where setName checks for the event and sets the new name according to your condition.

3) You can look into details of Angular Form Validation from here: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation